# How can I can sum elements of one column over fixed interval to be defined by the second column?

Tags: python, arrays, series

I have a DF of two columns A and B, I want to average the B elements based on each three different values of A :

```
A= [id1 id1 id1 id1 id2 id2 id2 id2 id3 id3 id3 id4 id4 id4 id4]
B=[1 2 3 4 4 2 1 1 1 3 3 4 4 4]
```

For each value of A, I want to sum two values of B and each time I shift with 1 value means :
for id1 :
The 1st value must be `1 +2` 
The second value must be `2+3` 
The third value must be `3+4` 
etc.
for id2
The 1st value must be `4 +2` 
The second value must be `2+1` 
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your values (a1, a2, ...) are numeric.

You can use `df.groupby` to get the mean of all the values of 'B' for a given A and then you can perform a rolling sum with a window size of 3. You will have to discard the last 2 rows in the dataframe to avoid any 'edge' effects caused by the rolling window.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5], 
                   'B': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})

mean_df = df.groupby('A')['B'].mean()

# perform the sum, reversing the order to do a forward sum
rolling_sum = mean_df.iloc[::-1].rolling(3, min_periods=0).sum().iloc[::-1]
```

Comment: The problem is that the size of window is not known I will edit my question to be clearer

Comment: I think I understand what you want.

For example, do you want to average all values of 'B' where 'A'=1 and then average all values of 'B' where 'A'=2 and so on... 

Then you want to calculate a rolling sum of these sum of these averages?

Comment: If the above comment is correct I have edited the answer to reflect what I now believe the question to be.

Comment: I think with three columns is better I will edit more my question

Comment: I'm sorry, your edits do not make the question any clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in a dataframe, with columns A and B, you can do:

```
 df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
```

Comment: and what about the shift?

Comment: what should the output be based on the shift?

Comment: I need the sum of each 3 values than I shift  I already mentioned in the question

Comment: im sorry, your question makes no sense to me